# Put a class to a link with an equivalent href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I have a lot of links:

```
<a href="put_id">1</a>
<a href="put_xs">1</a>
<a href="put_ws">1</a>
<a href="put_id">1</a>
<a href="put_id">1</a>
<a href="put_id">1</a>
<a href="put_lm">1</a>
<a href="put_mo">1</a>
<a href="put_sd">1</a>
<a href="put_id">1</a>
<a href="put_id">1</a>
```

I want to put a `class="print"`to all links which has a href of `put_id`. How will I do that using javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean `href`, is that right?

```
$('a[href="put_id"]').addClass("print");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a id="1" href="put_id">1</a> <a href="put_xs">1</a> <a href="put_ws">1</a> <a href="put_id">
                1</a> <a href="put_id">1</a> <a href="put_id">1</a> <a href="put_lm">1</a> <a href="put_mo">
                    1</a> <a href="put_sd">1</a> <a href="put_id">1</a> <a href="put_id">1</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="funappend('put_id');" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                var links1 = links[i].href;
                var link = links1.split("/");
                var linkslen = link.length;
                var reqlink = link[linkslen - 1];
                if (reqlink == "put_id") {
                    links[i].className = "print";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```